# HTML5LIB installation problems

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I have a Win 7 machine with Python 2.7 instlled and 3.5

2.7 is in C:\Python27

3.5 is in  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

I want to use html5lib import with my Python 2.7 installation

I can see its installed in the 3.5 directory

How do I installed it so its available for the 2.7 installation?

My path is

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ran the pop command using the full path for the directory when python 2.7 was installed.

Job jobbed!!!